# Why does my iOS application using cordova using excessive memory?

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I have my iOS application build using cordova framework completely with AngularJS, HTML and Javascript. I was just noticing the Debug Inspector that while the application usage, the memory is been used excessively whenever there is an ajax service call.

Also tried profiling using instruments and noticed the allocations keeps on increasing as in Debug Inspector.

I am sure that at some point of time the app may crash. How to solve this situation?

Any suggestions are most welcome?

[image]

Comment: I am experiencing a similar issue. You might have to build it without ajax.

Comment: I mentioned as ajax, because any framework like angular would use it internally.

Comment: That is true. I'd take a look at what resources the app is loading (using the Safari dev tools).